Posterior expectation of normal distribution with "truncated" observation
Consider the following problem of estimating an unknown parameter from normal samples:
Suppose that $\theta \sim N(0, \tau_\theta^{-1})$, where $\tau_\theta \ge 0$ is the prior precision.
Consider two random variables $X=\theta+\epsilon_X$ and $Y=\theta + \epsilon_Y$, where $\epsilon_X\sim N(0,\tau_X^{-1})$ and $\epsilon_Y\sim N(0,\tau_Y^{-1})$. The random variables $\epsilon_X$ and $\epsilon_Y$ are independent.
For some measurable set $A\subset \mathbb{R}$, I want to compute
$$E_{x,A}:=E[\theta \mid X=x,Y\in A].$$
One can think of $A$ as an interval, but I would like it to be more general if possible. As long as it does not pause some technical issue, I can assume a diffuse (uniform) prior, $\tau_\theta \to 0$.
Now, I know that if $A=\{y\}$, then $E_{x,A}=\gamma_X x+(1-\gamma_X) y$ with $\gamma_X:=\tau_X/(\tau_X+\tau_Y)$ (given uniform prior). If $A=\mathbb{R}$, this is also trivial. However, I am struggling to analyze $E_{x,A}$ for a general $A$. At least I would like to know if $E_{x,A}$ is linear in $x$, which is true for $A$ being singleton or entire real.
By the iterated law of conditional expectation, I can see that
\begin{align*}
E[\theta & \mid X,Y\in A]\\
 & =E[E[\theta\mid X,Y]\mid X,Y\in A]\\
 & =E[\gamma_{X}X+(1-\gamma_{Y})Y\mid X,Y\in A]\\
 & =\gamma_{X}X+(1-\gamma_{Y})E[Y\mid X,Y\in A]
\end{align*}
but I am not sure how to compute $E[Y\mid X,Y\in A]$.

This is equivalent to compute the posterior expectation of $\theta$ given $X\sim\mathcal N(\theta,\tau_X^{-1})$ and $Z=\mathbb I_A(Y)\sim\mathcal B(\mathbb P_\theta(Y\in A))$.

Does this answer your question? Multivariate Normal : expectation of X given Y is doubly-truncated

@xi'an Does $\mathbb{B}(p)$ mean the Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p$? I can compute $E[\theta \mid Z]$ and $E[\theta\mid X]$, but I am not sure what how to proceed for $E[\theta \mid X, Z]$, because the joint distribution of $(\theta, X, Z)$ is not clear.

@JarleTufto I am familiar with the result in the link, but I am not sure how to apply that to my question. I can compute $E[\theta \mid X], E[\theta\mid Y],  E[\theta \mid X, Y], E[\theta \mid Y\in A], E[X\mid Y\in A], E[X \mid Y]$ and $E[Y\mid X]$, but I am not sure about $E[\theta \mid X, Y\in A]$ and $E[Y \mid Y\in A, X]$

Since $Y\sim\mathcal N(\theta,\tau_Y^{-1})$, the indicator variable $Z=\mathbb I_A(Y)$ has a binomial distribution
$$Z\sim\mathcal B(\mathbb P_\theta(Y\in A))$$
Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, the joint distribution of $(X,Z)$ has density
$$\tau_X^{\tiny 1/2}\exp\{-\tau_X(x-\theta)^2/2\}\mathbb P_\theta(Y\in A)^z\mathbb P_\theta(Y\not\in A)^{1-z}$$
Under a flat prior on $\theta$, the posterior distribution is thus
$$\pi(\theta|x,z)\propto \exp\{-\tau_x(X-\theta)^2/2\}\mathbb P_\theta(Y\in A)^z\mathbb P_\theta(Y\not\in A)^{1-z}$$
and therefore
$$\mathbb E[\theta|x,z]=\dfrac{\int \theta \exp\{-\tau_X(x-\theta)^2/2\}\mathbb P_\theta(Y\in A)^z\mathbb P_\theta(Y\not\in A)^{1-z}\,\text d\theta}{\int \exp\{-\tau_X(x-\theta)^2/2\}\mathbb P_\theta(Y\in A)^z\mathbb P_\theta(Y\not\in A)^{1-z}\,\text d\theta}$$
whose value is most likely not available in closed form.
Now,
$$\tau_X\theta \exp\{-\tau_X(x-\theta)^2/2\}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\exp\{-\tau_X(x-\theta)^2/2\}+x\exp\{-\tau_X(x-\theta)^2/2\}$$
and
\begin{align}
\int &\theta \exp\{-\tau_X(x-\theta)^2/2\}\mathbb P_\theta(Y\in A)^z\mathbb P_\theta(Y\not\in A)^{1-z}\,\text d\theta\\
&= \tau_X^{-1}x\int \exp\{-\tau_x(x-\theta)^2/2\}\mathbb P_\theta(Y\in A)^z\mathbb P_\theta(Y\not\in A)^{1-z}\,\text d\theta\\
&\quad - \tau_X^{-1}\int  \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\exp\{-\tau_X(x-\theta)^2/2\}\mathbb P_\theta(Y\in A)^z\mathbb P_\theta(Y\not\in A)^{1-z}\,\text d\theta\\
&= \tau_X^{-1}x\int \exp\{-\tau_x(x-\theta)^2/2\}\mathbb P_\theta(Y\in A)^z\mathbb P_\theta(Y\not\in A)^{1-z}\,\text d\theta\\
&\quad + \tau_X^{-1} \int \exp\{-\tau_x(x-\theta)^2/2\}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\left[\mathbb P_\theta(Y\in A)^z\mathbb P_\theta(Y\not\in A)^{1-z}\right]\,\text d\theta\\
&= \tau_X^{-1}x\int \exp\{-\tau_x(x-\theta)^2/2\}\mathbb P_\theta(Y\in A)^z\mathbb P_\theta(Y\not\in A)^{1-z}\,\text d\theta\\
&\quad + \tau_X^{-1} \int \exp\{-\tau_x(x-\theta)^2/2\}\left[z\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\mathbb P_\theta(Y\in A)+(1-z)\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\mathbb P_\theta(Y\not\in A)\right]\,\text d\theta
\end{align}
which exhibits one linear dependence of the posterior mean on $X$ through the first term and a more complex dependence on $(X,Z)$ in the second term that is unlikely to be linear in $X$.
Note that
$$\sqrt{2\pi}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\mathbb P_\theta(Y\in A)
=\frac{\text d}{\text d\theta}\int_A \tau_Y^{\tiny 1/2}\exp\{-\tau_Y(y-\theta)^2/2\}\,\text dy\\
=\int_A \tau_Y^{\tiny 3/2}(y-\theta)\exp\{-\tau_Y(y-\theta)^2/2\}\,\text dy$$
does not help with simplification.

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\mathbb{E}[\theta\mid X=x,Y\in A] \\
&=\int_{y\in A}\mathbb{E}[\theta\mid X=x,Y=y]\, p_Y(y\mid X=x, Y\in A)\, dy\\
 &= \int_{y\in A}[\gamma_X x + (1-\gamma_X)y]\frac{\mathbb{P}(Y\in A\mid X=x,Y=y)\, p_Y(y\mid X=x)}{\mathbb{P}(Y\in A\mid X=x)}\, dy\\
&= \int_{y\in A}[\gamma_X x + (1-\gamma_X)y]\frac{p_Y(y\mid X=x)}{\mathbb{P}(Y\in A\mid X=x)}\, dy\\
&= \frac{\gamma_X x + (1-\gamma_X)\int_{y\in A}y\,p_Y(y\mid X=x)\, dy}{\mathbb{P}(Y\in A\mid X=x)}\\
&= \frac{\gamma_X x + (1-\gamma_X)\, \mathbb{E}[Y\cdot\mathbb{I}(Y\in A)\mid X=x]}{\mathbb{P}(Y\in A\mid X=x)}
\end{aligned}
$$
You might want to check this question and set of answers: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3254290/conditional-expectation-when-conditioning-on-a-set

\begin{gather*}
E[Y\mid X, Y\in A]=\frac{E[YI_A(Y)\mid X]}{E[I_A(Y)\mid X]}=\frac{\int_A yf_{Y|X}(y|x)dy}{\int_A f_{Y|X}(y|x)dy}=\frac{\int_A\int_R yf(_{\theta}, x,y)d_{\theta}dy}{\int_A\int_R f(_{\theta}, x,y)d_{\theta} dy}
\end{gather*}
